# calendar module take long time to load in vtiger5.4

Tags: php, mysql, vtiger

I am using vtiger 5.4 CRM in my website the calendar module taking 55 Sec with out any records please let me know anyone what i needs to be done i have check mysql query but that did not help me please suggest any regarding this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add code snippets if you want to be helped.

Comment: code snippets means?